# Automake with multiple test suites (coding/deployment)

Tags: automake

I'm using Automake for a project that is starting to have longer running integration/deployment style tests in addition to the typical unit tests. The issue is that during normal programming there is no need to run the longer tests, only the shorter set of unit tests. However, the final merge, and/or repository build, must run the complete test suite.

Is there a standard way to handle this with automake? Ideally I'd like to just have two targets, the normal `check` target to run everything and perhaps a `check-lite` to run the reduced test.

The project is spread across several sub-projects and directories, thus a standard automake approach would be ideal to ensure consistency.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest adding a `--enable-extended-tests` option to your `configure` script:

```
AC_MSG_CHECKING([whether to run extended tests])
AC_ARG_ENABLE([extended-tests],
  [AS_HELP_STRING([--enable-extended-tests], [run full integration tests])],
  [enable_extended_tests="yes"], [enable_extended_tests="no"])
AC_MSG_RESULT([$enable_extended_tests])

AM_CONDITIONAL([EXTENDED_TESTS], [test "X$enable_extended_tests" != "Xno"])
```

Then you can use an Automake conditional in your Makefile.am:

```
if EXTENDED_TESTS
EXTRA_TESTS = extra_test1 extra_test2 ...
else
EXTRA_TESTS =
endif

TESTS = $(EXTRA_TESTS) normal_test1 normal_test2 ...
```

Comment: That's an option, but usually we'll want to switch between the two test modes without rerunning automake.

Comment: You don't need to re-run `automake` with this solution, only `configure`.

Comment: Yes, I meant configure, which happens to be the slowest part of our build system unfortunately (thus we don't like running it too often)

Answer (score 0):

If you have split your test suite into separate directories based on the test type, then you can add some additional targets to the top level `Makefile.am` to do partial test suite runs.

For example, if your tree is organised as:

```
$(srcdir)
  - tests
     - unit
     - integration
```

You could add the following to the makefile:

```
check-unit:
    $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) -C tests/unit check

check-integration:
    $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) -C tests/integration check
```

Now when you run `make check-unit`, it will only run your unit tests.  And running `make check-integration` will run the other half of the tests.  The standard `make check` target will continue to run the whole suite.

If you can't organise all the tests under a single directory, you can add additional `$(MAKE)` invocations to the targets.  It does require some knowledge of the project structure at the top level, but there isn't a clear way to pass the required information up from the `Makefile.am` files in subdirectories.